# Resetear campo al pasar al siguiente mes

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

Tengo un valor en mi base de datos que me gustaría saber como puedo resetear ese valor a cero automáticamente al momento de que cambie de mes.

Es decir en el mes de octubre tiene este valor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al entrar el mes de noviembre automáticamente vaya a cero.

Comment: Intentastes algo? Prueba haciendo una funcion que saque el ultimo dia de este o todos los meses, despues has una condicion para que valide el dia de este mes y el ultimo dia + 1 y dentro de la condicion, pones lo que quieres(resetear el valor a cero). O asi lo veo yo, saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder me has dado una buena idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer uso de un [comando](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands) que se [ejecute](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands) al inicio de cada día y que evalúe si es el primer día del mes:

```
// MyCoolCommand.php

$startOfMonth = now()->startOfMonth();

if ($startOfMonth->diffInDays(now()) === 0) {
    // resetear valor
}
```

Para la comparación estoy utilizando el método `diffInDays()` de las [comparaciones de Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference).

Comment: Excelente gracias! Voy a ponerlo en ejecución ya mismo.

Comment: @JuanRivera en este caso no es necesario importar la librería pues `now()` retorna ya una instancia de Carbon